# Does Linux Shell execute fflush(stdout) first before executing and writing the result of the command passed by the user?

Tags: linux, shell, stdout, command-prompt, fflush

Let's say that I want to know my current working directory, so I type `pwd` in the prompt and press Enter.

Before getting my current working directory path, does the Linux Shell execute `fflush(stdout)` **FIRST**, and then do its stuff to return the path?

If so, why?

Comment: There is no "Linux Shell". The default shell on many Linux distributions is Bash, but this is by no means universal.

Comment: Do you type that fast?